# bst.unparse do not creates paranthesis and a clear indent

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, transpiler, ply

This is my ply.yacc code for binary operations.

```
def p_expression_add(p):
'''term : term ADD term
        | term SUB term
        | term MULTI term
        | term DIV term
        | term POW term'''

operator = ast_tree.Binary_operator(p[2])
operand1 = p[1]
operand2 = p[3]
p[0] = ast_tree.binary_operation(operator, operand1, operand2)
```

this is my ast code to represent the binary operations:

```
def binary_operation(operator, operand1, operand2):
    return ast.Expr(value=ast.BinOp(op=operator1, left=operand, right=operand2))
```

firstly, I am creating an AST object then unparse it back to python.
but it gives a non parenthesis and wrong indent output for binary calculations.

[image: **** output of my code****]

[image: the expected output should be]

Is there a way to solve it or where is my mistake ?
thank you.

Comment: There are just way too many typos in the code you pasted. Please create an actually functional snippet of about the size of the code you pasted. Before inserting it in the question, *test it to make sure it does what you say it does*, and then paste both the input and the output *as text, not as images*. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the answer and correction I am still learning how to use here, for my own questions. I will be careful next time. best regards.

Answer (score 0):

it was happening because I was creating ast.Expr() for every operation that I did.

```
  def binary_operation(operator, operand1, operand2):
        return ast.Expr(value=ast.BinOp(op=operator1, left=operand, right=operand2)
```

as you can see in this code snippet whenever the program make a binary operation it will create another expression and ast.unparse will print that expression in another line. I learnt that we need to be careful when playing with python's ast.

for now the correct version is...

```
def binary_operation(operator, operand1, operand2):
      return ast.BinOp(op=operator1, left=operand, right=operand2)
```

until I got stuck in another problem that has correlation with this problem.